# ejabberd - Connecting two users through the API

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am using ejabberd as the XMPP server in my ASP.Net project. How do I programmatically connect or friend two users? Is there some way to access the ejabberd API? Any pointers to code samples would be great.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jadahl/mod_restful look at think it may help you out.